# spring auth error No AuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to build auth system with Spring Boot Security.
So I have custom auth provider (without @Component annotation)

```
public class CustomAuthProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if (authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            return authentication;
        }

        if ("user".equals(name) && "password".equals(password)) {

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    name, password, new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"))));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }
}
```

which declared as a bean

```
@Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        final CustomAuthProvider authProvider = new CustomAuthProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return authProvider;
    }
```

Here is configuration:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(
            AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/anonymous*").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/registration*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login");
    }
```

When I'm trying post query to localhost:8080/login I'm getting sign-in form with message

> No AuthenticationProvider found for
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

Comment: can you add the request you post to /login?

Comment: @slimane does it matter with such error? I send simple post with few fields (email and password) without headers via Postman

Comment: your exception doesn't only reflect messing authprovider, it can be also that your authprovider had an exception while processing your request

Comment: @slimane https://pastebin.com/SzT0t1Yu

Answer (score 1):

spring's default request parameters for authentication are: `username` and `password`
you are sending `email` instead of `username` so it throws an exception somewhere in your authentication manager.

if you want to override the default values you can simply specify that in your HTTP security configs:

```
.formLogin()
    .loginProcessingUrl("/login") 
    .usernameParameter("email")
    .passwordParameter("password")
```

Comment: it would be nice if we can access your code, is it possible to have it publicly?

Comment: it seems that I need to send data with form-data